# How to identify electric motors, find pinouts, etc

Tags: mechanical-engineering, electrical-engineering, motors

This is my first question here so I apologize if I do anything wrong in making this post.

I recently pulled the electric motors out of two junked home appliances (a 120v clothes washing machine and a 240v electric clothes dryer) for prospective use in a machine I'd like to build (a large rotary tumbler). Unfortunately, unlike retail motors, these included very little in the way of nameplate information (and in the case of the washing machine motor, no nameplate information whatsoever). Both of the motors have multiple wire leads (like half a dozen).

So in order to even evaluate whether either of these motors would be appropriate for my intended use (ideally I would like high-torque, low-RPM motors to minimize the amount of gearing necessary) or if I'd be able to build/source adequate control circuitry I need to figure out what type of motors they are, if they run on AC or DC, what voltages need to be applied to which leads, frequencies, RPMs, etc. etc.

I've Google searched the part numbers listed on the motors and while they appear to be very commonly used motor models (in many, many models of household appliances), I have been unable to find technical data, pinouts, etc.

Here is all the information I know about the two motors:

Motor #1 (dryer):
Part # W10396029
Model # S58SVMZK-6925
Label says "120/60 5.4A" which I interpret to mean 120v 60Hz (which suggests AC), 5.4 amps
Leads: Two large-gauge red wires, one small-gauge wire each of black, blue, white, and green/yellow.

Motor #2 (washing machine):
Part # W10419333**
Leads: 8 different small-gauge wires: 1 each of red, dark blue, yellow, gray, brown, pink, orange, and light blue.
There is no other information anywhere on the motor.

Any thoughts anyone has about identifying these, finding the technical data, pinouts, etc., or figuring out how to correctly operate them, would be greatly appreciated.

I will try to attach photos to this post.

Motor #1
[image: Motor 1]

Motor #1 wiring harness
[image]

Motor #2 stator and drive axle
[image]

Motor #2 part #
[image]

Comment: Hello, Do you have the model and brand of the machines from which you removed these motors? Sometimes you can get the machine diagram and find how the motors are connected (and the function of the wires!).

Comment: The first motor really is AC. For the speed, hard to say, it would be necessary to check the motor poles. A google search [motor S58SVMZK-6925 "rpm"] suggests something between 1450 (6 pole) and 1750 rpm (4 pole) in 60Hz.

Comment: While this is an okay location for your question. The electrical engineering stackexchange has more users (like 7x more) and will be better suited to answer your question. 
https://electronics.stackexchange.com/
Definitely swing back here for other engineering questions!